# ¿Cómo imprimir linea de separacion y mostrar una sola vez datos repetidos en reporte generado en jasper report?

Tags: jasper-reports

Tengo que generar un reporte que se muestre de la siguiente forma:

Nombre | Apellido | Debe | Haber |Saldo Parcial

separar con una linea  solo cuando cambie de cliente y mostrar una sola vez nombre y apellido.

¿Cómo lo puedo hacer?, no he encontrado mucha información .

Comment: ummm no entiendo muy bien,¿podrias plasmar los dos ejemplos en una imagen?

Comment: @AquilesPerez
Esto es lo que tengo:

Nombre | Apellido |Debe | Haber |Saldo Parcial
Matias      Blanco    0          0          0
Matias      Blanco    10         0        -10
Matias      Blanco     0         10         0


Esto es lo que quiero :

Nombre | Apellido |Debe | Haber |Saldo Parcial
Matias      Blanco    0          0          0
                               10         0        -10
                                0         10         0
----------------------------------------------------------------

Comment: (Nombre, apellido, debe, haber, saldo) Son etiquetas no?, luego todos los datos, deberian ir en el detalle, ya que asumo que son muchas filas que traes de una consulta.

Comment: @AquilesPerez Si, eso lo hago, pero a lo que me refiero es que si la consulta me devuelve 20 filas de Matías Blanco solo mostrar el nombre la primera vez que aparece.

Comment: ummm pues entonces, deberias extraer el nombre en una sola variable, y por aparte, todos los movimientos que tiene, esa es opcion uno, la otra es que desde codigo, recorras el arreglo y dejes vacio todos las demas filas de las columnas(nombre, Apellido) del resultado, exceptuando la primera.

Comment: @AquilesPerez Perfecto, pensé que habría alguna manera de hacerlo desde jasper con alguna sentencia if. Pero voy a tomar la idea de recorrer antes el arreglo y eliminar los nombres repetidos. Gracias.

Comment: Excelente man, lastimosamente no conozco algo que haga el jasperReport, me suele suceder siempre que hago reportes  con consultas que tienen JOIN , a veces esmas facil resolverlo desde codigo.

Answer (score 0):

Tal vez sea un poco tarde, pero para el que aun no sepa como hacer eso, simplemente tienes que crear un subReporte dentro de ese reporte y le pasas la lista nada más. Tu lista debe tener esta estructura:

```
//Esto tiene toda la información del cliente que pasaras a tu reposte    
List<Cliente> listaCliente = traerInfoDeBaseDatos();
```

y tu clase Cliente deberia tener esto:

```
private String nombre;
private String apellido;
private List<SaldoParcial> saldoParcial;

//Getters y Setters
```

Entonces en tu reporte le pasas un Fields nombre, otro Fields apellido, etc segun cuantos atributos tengas (recuerda que los nombre de los Fields tienen que tener el mismo que el de tu Bean en este caso de la clase Cliente, respetando mayusculas y todo, osea tal cual). y Tambien le pasas al subReporte la Lista osea "saldoParcial".

De esa manera va crear el reporte por cada cliente su respectiva lista y con eso deberia funcionar.

Dato extra: si quieres que el nombre se centre respecto al tamaño de la lista que se genera en el subReporte tienes que ponerlo en sus propiedades Stretch Type = "ContainerHeight" del Fields que quieres centrar y listo.

Espero que esto sirva de ayuda para quien aun lo necesite. Saludos